# Angularjs and JQuery passing data between pages

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I'm currently trying to develope a webapp with AngularJs and Jquery mobile.

I have the following code on index.html file

```
<ul>
<li>
<input type="hidden" value="cat">
<a href="#details">Cat</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<input type="hidden" value="dog">
<a href="#details">Dog</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

My angularjs data looks like the following

```
$scope.cats = [{name:'Cat1'},{name:"Cat2"},{name:"Cat3"}]

$scope.dogs = [{name:'Dog1'},{name:"Dog2"},{name:"Dog3"}]
```

I already have an inline page called  #details.

So, what i need is when user clicks on "cat" , #details page should be open with

```
<ul ng-repeat="cat in cats"><li>{{cat.name}}</li><ul>
```

when user clicks on "dog" , #details page should be open with

```
<ul ng-repeat="cat in cats"><li>{{cat.name}}</li><ul>
```

Please do help in this.
(Sorry for my Bad English)

Comment: In detail page you have to pass clicked animal name right? like #details/cat1, #details/dog1 etc

Comment: Is there any other way instead of passing values via URL parameter. It works but does not works on android mobile when compiled to a webui app.

Comment: Which framework you are use for hybrid development?

Comment: I use Jquery mobile